# Comparing imputed data correlation matrix to that of the original data

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I extracted a correlation matrix from imputed data using MICE. What approach would I use to measure the similarity between the correlation matrix from the imputed data and the correlation matrix from my original data? Although I'm dealing with two sets of data (imputed and original) would it be possible to test for significant differences between these correlation matrices?